# Prove that $E(X_1 \dots X_n)^\frac{1}{n} \leq (EX_1 \dots EX_n)^\frac{1}{n}$, with $X_i$ uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> Let $X_1, \dots , X_n$ i.i.d. uniformly distributed random variables
>   with $f(x) = 1_{(0,1)}(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\Pi_n = (X_1
>  \dots X_n)^\frac{1}{n}$ and $M_n = \max \{ X_1, \dots , X_n \}$. Prove
>   the following:
>
> - $E(X_1 \dots X_n)^\frac{1}{n} \leq (EX_1 \dots EX_n)^\frac{1}{n}$
> - $P(\Pi_n \leq M_n) = 1$.

Already I showed that  $E \Pi_n = (1 - \frac{1}{n+1})^n = (\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ and $(EX_1\dots EX_n)^\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$. So now my plan was to use induction to prove the first statement. It clearly holds for $n=1$. Next is to show that $(\frac{n+1}{n+2})^{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2}$, using $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n \leq \frac{1}{2}$. But I don't see how to prove that, hoping this is the right approach for the problem.

For the second part I was thinking to say $(\Pi_{i=1}^n x_i)^\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq \max\{x_1, \dots , x_n\}$. Would that suffice?

Comment: Yes and yes....

Comment: @Lost1 How should I continu with the induction?

Comment: Why do you need induction? Note $(n/(n+1))^n$ is DECREASING to 1/e. This is just a proof why 1 over this is increasing to e. For a proof of that, use google.